# How to send the name and value off the textbox to ajax which is used in php for validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So i am trying to send the name and value of the textbox to ajax and want to use that name of the text box in php to validate the field. I was trying to use this.name but apparently its not the correct way!. 
This is my ajax code.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function frmValidation(str) 
    {
        if (str=="") 
        {
            document.getElementById("txtError").innerHTML="";
            return;
        } 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } 
        else 
        {  
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
        {
            document.getElementById("txtError").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","validation.php?value="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }  
    }
```

And thats my html

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="First Name">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" onblur="frmValidation(this.value)" tabindex="1" id="First Name" placeholder="First Name" name="fname"><span id="txtError" style="color: red"></span>
            </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see you using `this.name`

Answer (score 0):

Change to pass in `this` so you can access `this.name` and `this.value` inside the function

```
<input onblur="frmValidation(this)" ....>
```

JS

```
function frmValidation(elem){
    var str = elem.value, name =elem.name;

    //.....

     xmlhttp.open("GET","validation.php?value="+str + '&name='+name,true);

     //....

}
```

Since question is tagged jQuery can replace `onblur` with:

```
$('input').blur(function(){
    $.get('validation.php', {name: this.name, value:this.value))
        .done(function(resp){
           $('#txtError').html(resp);
        });    
});
```